# Permisos para escribir archivos en mi memoria Local con NET MAUI en Android 13

Tags: c#, android, permisos, maui

mi APP tiene que recibir un archivo, cualquiera fuera la fuente del mismo (mail, web, etc.), descargarlo en mi HD/SSD local del teléfono con Android 13, y poder leerlo/editarlo.
Para esto estoy usando el paquete CommunityToolkit.Maui;
La función folderPicker para seleccionar donde tengo el archivo.
Agrego los permisos en el Manifiesto de Android:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Pero cuando ejecuto al APP, selecciono el archivo, me solicita los permisos, los Acepto, pero a la hora de trabajar con el archivo de da el siguiente error:

> Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Nueva/archivo.txt' is denied

Si ejecuto esta misma App con una versión de Android 8, puedo abrir el archivo correctamente.

Gracias.

---

También (como me lo indican) estoy solicitando los permisos en tiempo de ejecución de la siguiente manera:

```
    internal class InfoPermisos : BasePlatformPermission
{
#if ANDROID
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions =>
        new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
        {
        (global::Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, true),
        (global::Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, true)
        }.ToArray();
#endif
}
```

la cual llamo antes de seleccionar el archivo con

```
async Task RequesPermisos()
 {
     if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Android)
         return;
     var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

     if (DeviceInfo.Version.Major >=12)
     {
         status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<InfoPermisos>();
         if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
             return;
         if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<InfoPermisos>())
         {
             await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Necesita Permisos", "Because!!!", "OK");
         }
         status= await Permissions.RequestAsync<InfoPermisos>();
     }
     else
     {
         status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
         if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
             return;
         if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>())
         {
             await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Necesita Permisos", "Because!!!", "OK");
         }

         status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
     }

     if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
         await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Permission Requerido",
             "Permisos Requerido para escribir archivos. " +
             "Por favor Acepte permiso.", "OK");
 }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Estás pidiendo permiso al usuario en tiempo de ejecución? Recuerda que ya desde hace algunas versiones existe esto. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419

Comment: Hola, si estoy pidiendo permiso. antes de seleccionar el archivo.

Answer (score 0):

**Si tu apps compilada es orientada a un sistema operativo menor a Android 10**

Lo único que necesitas es realizar la petición manual

```
#if ANDROID
public async Task<bool> RequestPermissionAsync()
{
    var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Current activity is null");

    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage))
    {
        await Toast.Make("Please grant access to external storage", ToastDuration.Short, 12).Show();
    }

    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, new[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 1);

    return false;
}
```

llamando la función de esta forma:

```
#if ANDROID

        await RequestPermissionAsync();
```

**Apps compiladas con Android 10 (Level 29) o posterior**

El problema que presentas, indica que no puedes acceder a una ruta de tu dispositivo

> Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Nueva/archivo.txt' is
> denied

La razón por la que no se permite el escribir o acceder a la ruta que presentas, es que actualmente (apps compiladas con Android 10 (Level 29) o posterior) no puedes realizarlo fuera de la estructura de archivos que genera tu app, esto por cuestiones de seguridad. Aunque definas el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` no es necesario), y el usuario lo acepte manualmente, tu aplicación no te permitirá acceder a la ruta que deseas.

Actualmente, únicamente puedes crear archivos dentro de la estructura de archivos que genera tu aplicación:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/
```

---

**Es importante mencionar que actualmente es necesaria la petición manual del permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, no únicamente ser definida en el `AndroidManifest.xml`**

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Jorge, lo de crear los archivos dentro de la estructura de mi app, lo lei por lo q también intente crear una copia del archivo seleccionado en el directorio de mi APP, pero tampoco me dejaba. Voy a probar petición manual como me lo indicas. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ok, entonces si estás escribiendo y leyendo dentro de la estructura de tu app, solo necesitas la petición manual de permisos. @Ezequiel Actualmente es necesaria la petición manual de permisos, no únicamente ser definida en el AndroidManifest,xml